# Python checking for negative values

Tags: python

Take the following code below. It should raise and error if the value (int) is a negative value:

```
if up_votes > 0 or down_votes > 0:
   raise ValueError('cannot be negative.')
```

However, when I input `up_votes=100` and `down_votes=100` this evaluates as `True`. Why?

Comment: Is this a trick question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be like this

You are using the `greater than sign [>]` instead of `lesser then sign [<]`

```
if up_votes < 0 or down_votes < 0:
  raise ValueError('cannot be negative.')
```

**Sample:**

```
up_votes=-10
down_votes=-10
if up_votes < 0 or down_votes < 0:
raise ValueError('cannot be negative.')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-2b318d5e4006> in <module>()
    1 up_votes=-10
    2 if up_votes < 0 or down_votes < 0:
----> 3   raise ValueError('cannot be negative.')
    4 

ValueError: cannot be negative.
```

**A more generic sample:**

```
1<0
False

-1<0
True
```